# Asp.NET MVC -- Fileupload image value shows null values in httppost method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MultipartForms in Which I Could upload an Image and other form values.While, the form values are rightfully received through the FormCollection Property whereas the Upload file always shows the null value in HttpPostedFileBase Property.I go through forums but I couldn't get Where went Wrong. Here, Is What I done Please go through it and Said what Went Wrong.Thanks friend.

```
enter code here
```

cshtml:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "StaffRegistration", FormMethod.Post, new  { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
 <input type="file" name="StaffImage" id="StaffImage" />
 }
```

> Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection,HttpPostedFileBase File)
 {
 try
 {
 // TODO: Add insert logic here


 StaffRegistration StaffReg = new StaffRegistration();

 StaffReg.FirstName = collection["FirstName"].ToString();
 StaffReg.LastName = collection["LastName"].ToString();
 StaffReg.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(collection["DateofBirth"]);
 StaffReg.Nationality = collection["Nationality"].ToString();
 StaffReg.Gender = collection["Gender"].ToString(); 
 StaffReg.MaritalStatus = collection["MaritalStatus"].ToString();
 StaffReg.BloodGroup = collection["BloodGroup"].ToString();
 StaffReg.StaffName = collection["StaffName"].ToString();
 StaffReg.MiddleName = collection["MiddleName"].ToString();
 HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["StaffImage"];

 StaffRegistrationBusSer StaffRegBusSer = new StaffRegistrationBusSer();
 StaffRegBusSer.AddStaffReg(StaffReg,file);

 return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

> DataLayer

```
public bool AddStaffRegistraiton(StaffRegistration staffRegistration,HttpPostedFileBase File)
 {
 staffRegistration.StaffImage = ConvertToByte(File);

 using(SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
 {
 SqlParameter paramImage = new SqlParameter();
 paramImage.ParameterName = "@StaffImage";
 paramImage.Value = staffRegistration.StaffImage;
 Cmd.Parameters.Add(paramImage);
 Con.Open();
 Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 }
 return true;
 }

ConvertToByte function:

 public byte[] ConvertToByte(HttpPostedFileBase Image)
 {
 byte[] imagebyte = null;
 BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(Image.InputStream);
 imagebyte = Reader.ReadBytes((int)Image.ContentLength);
 return imagebyte;
 }
```

Comment: Your file input has `name="StaffImage"` so the parameter in the POST method must match - `public ActionResult Create(StaffReg model, HttpPostedFileBase StaffImage)` - not also change the 1st parameter to your model (you should never need to use `FormCollection`)

Comment: Could you please add the request and response from browser console while uploading file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cshtml page:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new  { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StaffName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StaffName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StaffName)
            </div>
        </div>


      <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="StaffImage" id="StaffImage" />
            </div>
        </div>
 }
```

*Actually I have to include multipart/form in View level, Instead of the particular upload files.Then, I Modified like this in .cshtml page. Now, my code works fine*